# Multisite - sort merged get_posts() queries

Tags: multisite, get-posts

I have a multisite (test) installation of WordPress and want to get the posts of every blog.

After hours, I got the solution for that. But now, I have the merged query and like to sort the posts from each blog by date. Now I get the blog1-posts and after all blog1-posts, I get the blog2-posts.

How to sort the array? Here is the code so far:

```
$custom_posts = array();

$blog_ids = wp_get_sites();

foreach ($blog_ids as $key=>$current_blog) {

    switch_to_blog($current_blog['blog_id']);

    $query = get_posts("posts_per_page=10");

    $custom_posts = array_merge($custom_posts, $query);

    restore_current_blog();

}

//SORT THE $custom_posts BY POST_DATE? HOW? :(

global $post; 

foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

<<< theposts >>>.
.
endforeach;
```

I hope this is possible to do.

Or is there any better way to reach the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the new (4.7+) [`wp_list_sort()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_sort/) utility function that's a wrapper for `WP_List_Util::sort()` that uses `usort()` or `uasort()`.

**Example 1:**

Sort by descending *post date*

```
$sorted_custom_posts = wp_list_sort( 
    $custom_posts, 
    'post_date', 
    'DESC' 
);
```

**Example 2:**

Sort by descending *post date* and ascending post *title*

```
$sorted_custom_posts = wp_list_sort( 
    $custom_posts, 
    [
        'post_date'  => 'DESC',
        'post_title' => 'ASC',
    ]
);
```

Check the *Make* post [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/02/wp_list_sort-and-wp_list_util-in-4-7/) for more information.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That's so easy if you know that :D
Before you posted the answer, I found this solution, but your's is my favorite! Thank you very very much!
usort($custom_posts, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b->post_date_gmt, $a->post_date_gmt);
});

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped. @Markus